# Bandwidth regulation without QoS and VLAN

Tags: switch, router, vlan, qos, voip

Does anyone know any possibility to do Bandwidth reservation or something equal to it. Mainly to give VoIP and IPTV Bandwidth before the Internet when there is no possibility to use QoS and VLAN.

It should be possible to automatically detect the device connected to the port (based on MAC address or device name) and then enable either VLAN X if its a IPTV Box connected or VLAN Y if its a SOHO Router connected.

Any input may it be another View to the situation or a maybe possible solution is kindly requested.

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for products/resources. Almost all enterprise-grade network equipment is capable of doing this. QoS marking (when the devices do not mark traffic) and queuing, shaping, policing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and Heading contradicts each other.In description you mentioned that you want to achieve it without using VLAN and QOS.However,In description you have mentioned that "enable either VLAN X if its a IPTV Box connected or VLAN Y if its a SOHO Router connected".

Given that,the best method is to use QOS and VLAN to achieve your requirement.There is also another method do it using a different way. **Iptables + tc in a linux based router**

**Identifier for Device:**
You can use the Option 60 in DHCP request.Vendor Class identifier to understand the type of device connected.

**Bandwidth rate limiting Logic**

You can use both iptables policies and tc to limit the bandwidth for particular devices with different Vendor class identifier.

Since your query doesn't have more details about the bandwidth rate or name of vendor class identifiers.I will just give some sample commands for your reference.

Sample TC rule for 100mbps

> tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit

I'm sure if you explore both tc and iptables,you should be able to come up with a script to achieve your requirement.It is good to use an openW.R.T based router with tc support for your setup.

Note: The best solution is to use VLAN + QOS solution.

**EDITED based on the Comment**

A good router/Gateway/CPE at the customer end can solve this problem. I belive what you are trying to achieve is to provide seamless services to your end customers.

1. Faster connectivity to End Customer and Priority for the SetTop Box Traffic in your network.Constraint: STB doesn't support QOS.
2. SOHO router packets need to be considered with lower priority and treated in a differnt VLAN.

Do you have access/own the Gateway/Router at the Customer Premise.If yes,then Scheduling and Prioritizing the packets with different queues can provide a solution for this.

Option #1: Using vendor class idetifier

Assuming that an STB can be identified using DHCP option 60 in the network,You can tag all the packets from STB with Higher priority with (eg. "CS5" for Broadcast Video).Similarly you can tag all the SIP/RTP packets with "EF" priority and rest of the packets in Best effort queue. This will help you to maintain a good QOS for customers.

Option #2:

Why don't you create and establish different PPPOE from WAN (at Router)based on the service.

1. PPP_IPTV for STB services at 122.123.124.125 IP range.
2. PPP_Data for Default data at 172.15.45.1
3. PPP_VOIP for VOIP services at 181.44.22.44

IP address mentioned above is arbitrary.

Comment: maybe my english is bad but in my opinion it is not a disclosure of each other - vlan can be a solution but only if it is not bound to a specific port (what it is on my knowledge) - the main problem is our iptv-boxes aren't capable of QoS so we used different vlans to solve this issue till now - as we are getting bigger eg. get more customers the support gets overwelming and a big part of the support is to explain our customer that they have to put the different devices (phone, tv-box, router) in the specific ports - so we now wanna have a onevlan solution

Comment: Edited the Answer based on your inputs.

Comment: thanks for your input i will give it a try the PPPOE thing sounds like it maybe a good starting point - dhcp options we already tested works in our own network but not on the one of our other ISP on their network we only provide our services also parts of their network are layer 2 only

Comment: Okay,Please feel free to raise queries or need more help on this.

Comment: thanks for you help in the meantime - the problem got solved by a firmware update of ourIP TV-Boxes

Comment: Ohh..Great.Just out of curiosity,Did they implemented DSCP tagging for all the IPTV  packets(IGMP)?

Comment: sry didn't see you posted a question to my last comment. They made the Boxes configureable so we can decide wether we wanna add the EF Flag or any other to all the packets.